# Preserve port in url (nginx)

Tags: linux, nginx, port-forwarding

I am trying to run nginx server to show some folders, so users could see theirs content and download files. But I want nginx to listen port say 80 inside docker container, but outside it will be say server.com:1080. This external routing is already setted up.

The welcome page works, but when I access the folder through `server.com:1080/folder` url changes to `server.com:80/folder` and a "can't connect to the address" page is displayed. I am very novice in Nginx, so I tried some things like changing server_name and adding proxy_pass without good understanding of theirs meaning, but was unable to make it work properly. Maybe I don't know some specific term for this situation and therefore can't google matching solution.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be according to best practice but, in my opinion, one way would be to redirect the subdirectory to root:

1- open the Nginx configuration file:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

2- add the following location block:

```bash
location ^~ /folder {
      rewrite ^/folder(.*)$ $1 last; 
}
```

I'm sure you've already done this since you say the welcome page works fine, but are you sure you've mapped the host port into the container port properly?

Comment: No, this doesn't work, "location directive is not allowed in nginx.conf. Putting into sites-enabled/default - too.


This is not me who setted up routing between external and internal docker ports, but since it shows welcome page it is apparently working properly. Or your question is much deeper than I understand

Comment: Can you share the output of `docker port <nginx-container-name>`?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have access to the outside. Nginx is not in my own additional container, I installed it as a program while working in terminal inside container

Comment: So if I've understood correctly, there is no Docker container running from an nginx Docker image and you've installed nginx via `apt` or any other package manager inside an already running container, correct?

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is that `folder/` links do basically work (don't change the port). The only addition was necessary to fix 403 Forbidden: `autoindex on` and now it shows folders, subfolders and allow files downloading. Pretty enough for me. So no other tricks necessary:

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    autoindex on;
}
```